# Showing the right half of the unit hyperbola is a complete metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be given as follows.

$$f(\theta) = (\cosh \theta, \sinh \theta)$$

I want to argue that $\mathrm{im}(f)$ is a complete metric space with respect to the [Riemannian metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Riemannian_metrics). What theorems are available to do this? I'm looking for something along the lines of:

1. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, and
2. since $f$ is "sufficiently nice", hence

by the theorem I'm looking for, $\mathrm{im}(f)$ is a complete metric space with respect to the Riemannian metric.

Comment: Do you mean the pullback via inclusion of the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ or the metric that pulls back via $f$ to the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Travis, I mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Riemannian_metrics); it is not just the restriction of the usual metric to $\mathrm{im}(f)$.

Comment: When I say metric, I do mean Riemannian metric (rather than metric in the sense of metric space). More precisely, do you mean the pullback to the hyperbola $H$ via inclusion of the standard Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ or the Riemannian metric on $H$ that pulls back to the standard Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @Travis, sorry, I don't understand the difference. What is a pullback in this context? I am somewhat familiar with pullbacks from category theory, but my knowledge of Reimannian geometry is rather primitive.

Comment: If we have a smooth map $f: M \to N$ and a Riemannian metric $g$ on $N$, we get a *pullback* metric on $M$, defined by $(f^* g)(X, Y) = g(f_* X, f_* Y)$. I assume you mean you want the metric pulled back from $\mathbb{R}^2$, as with the other metric there's no reason to mention $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of $\theta$ the Riemannian metric on the half-hyperbola $H$ is given by

$$ds=|f'(\theta)|\>d\theta=\sqrt{\sinh^2\theta +\cosh^2\theta}\ \ d\theta\ .$$

Now the variable $\theta$, where $-\infty<\theta<\infty$,  is a global coordinate on  $H$. Therefore the map
$$\sigma:\quad H\to{\mathbb R},\qquad f(\theta)\mapsto\int_0^\theta \sqrt{1+2\sinh^2\theta}\ \ d\theta\ ,\tag{1}$$
which sends the point $f(\theta)\in H$ to the signed length of the arc from $(1,0)\in H$ to $f(\theta)$, is an isometry from the Riemannian manifold $H$ to ${\mathbb R}$ with its standard metric. Since ${\mathbb R}$ is known to be complete it follows that $H$ is complete as well.

Unfortunately the integral on the right in $(1)$ is elliptic, so that $\sigma$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.